# Meaning of "Unlooked for joy in that I honor most" in a sonnet by Shakespeare

Tags: phrase-meaning, poetry, early-modern-english

Shakespeare ([sonnet 25](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/45089/sonnet-25-let-those-who-are-in-favour-with-their-stars)):

> Let those who are in favor with their stars
>   Of public honor and proud titles boast,
>   Whilst I, whom fortune of such triumph bars,
>   **Unlooked for joy in that I honor most**.
>   Great princes' favorites their fair leaves spread
>   But as the marigold at the sun’s eye,
>   And in themselves their pride lies burièd,
>   For at a frown they in their glory die.
>   The painful warrior famousèd for worth,
>   After a thousand victories once foiled,
>   Is from the book of honor razèd quite,
>   And all the rest forgot for which he toiled.
>     Then happy I that love and am belovèd
>     Where I may not remove nor be removèd.

I don't understand the basic meaning of the bolded line. Where is the verb? Is it "joy" = "to feel enjoyment"?

Could we rephrase it thus:

> Whilst I, whom fortune of such triumph bars,
>   Unlooked-for, **feel enjoyment** in the things I honor most.

One other option I came up with is "I boast in unlooked-for joy", but then I cannot make sense of the rest of the sentence: "in that I honor most".

But wait, my first option is also shaky, because it's "that" and not "what" (I honor most).

Comment: "The hidden joy I receive from being loved" is what he is saying.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 - so the whole sentence has no verb? "Whilst I, whom fortune of such triumph bars, the hidden joy I received from being loved" makes no sense. Is it an omission of "boast"? (I boast of "unlooked-for joy") Still it fails to glue together for me.

Comment: No. He is not boasting. It is the silent secret pleasure of being saved by love while suffering lifes arduous misfortunes. Yes, there is no explicit verb I can see, but a grammarian may offer a more explicit response. I would imply the hidden verbs of __feel__, __know__ , __recieve__ or __experience__.

Comment: The verb is *to joy*. *Unlook'd  for* is, according to websites, either an adjective (describing the speaker) or an adverb describing the verb *joy*.

Comment: A modern dialect might use "that which I honor most" or "what I honor most" or even "whom I honor most".  In this dialect, "that" can stand alone -- with the advantage of not distinguishing between "what" and "whom".  The reader doesn't know whether a person is involved until the closing couplet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. The early modern 'joy' was a verb as well as a noun. So the meaning is essentially:

> So I - whose fortune has only been to be someone unimportant - being unknown, take pleasure in the thing I honor most (the object of my unrequited love). But whereas courtiers' and soldiers' joy is shallow and easily overturned, I can never be rejected as my beloved doesn't even know I want her [or him - this is a point of contention].

Phonically I think the stressed syllable helps hint that it's a verb, too.

Answer (score 1):

The sonnet's fourth line is more ambiguous than what the other answer and the comment's suggest. For a starter, here is my paraphrase of the first three lines:

> Let those whose stars are favourable 
> boast about (or possibly even "display proudly") public honour and splendid titles
> while I, prevented (from) such triumphs by (bad) fortune, ...

The fourth line needs to be discussed separately, due to the ambiguity of "unlooked for":

- "Unlooked for" may mean "ignored, overlooked" (Colin Burrow). The line may then be interpreted as "(while I), (being) ignored, take delight in the object or person that I honour most". ("Honour" in this line contrast with the "public honour" in the second line.)
- "Unlooked for" may mean "unregarded, out of the public eye" (Kerrigan). This is a slightly different nuance than the first meaning that brings out the contrast with "public honour" even more strongly.
- "Unlooked for" may mean "unexpectedly" (Kerrigan), resulting in the following reading: "(while I), unexpectedly / beyond expectation take delight in the object or person that I honour most".

Sources:

- Shakespeare, William: *The Sonnets and A Lover's Complaint*. Edited by John Kerrigan. The New Penguin Shakespeare. London: Penguin, 1986. (458 pages)
- Shakespeare, William: *The Complete Sonnets and Poems*. Edited by Colin Burrow. The Oxford Shakespeare. Oxford: Oxford University Press, 2002 [2008]. (750 pages)