# on the top or on top

Tags: prepositions, articles

Which one of these is grammartically correct to tell students during the examination

1) Please, write down your name on the top of the answer sheet.
2) Please, write down your name on top of the answer sheet.

Thank you

Comment: I would say "at the top" but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: @CowperKettle I am. Go for it.

Comment: "Write your name at the top of the answer sheet, please." But I run a more [authoritative classroom](http://www.jadeannrivera.com/authoritative-teaching-and-gifted-children/), so this may not work in all classrooms.

Comment: @StoneyB - you might [like this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/115926/meaning-of-unlooked-for-joy-in-that-i-honor-most-in-a-sonnet-by-shakespeare) - I'm still not sure whether "unlooked-for" relates to the author.

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences are grammatically correct.  To add to your 2 sentences, you could also use

- Please, write your name down on the top of the answer sheet
- Please write your name on the top of the answer sheet
- Please write your name down on top of the answer sheet
- Please, write down your name **at** the top of the answer sheet

(Source: [Word References](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/write-down-your-name-or-write-your-name-down.921013/))